# Query latest record by date and group by a serial column

Tags: mysql

I have data like this

```
--------------------------------
Date                Serial   State
2016-04-30 20:34:47     4    0
2016-04-30 20:34:48     5    0
2016-04-30 20:35:10     4    0
2016-04-30 20:35:08     5    1
```

I am trying to query the latest timestamp for each serial with it's associate state so it would be like this

```
Date                Serial   State
2016-04-30 20:35:10     4    0
2016-04-30 20:35:08     5    1
```

This seemed to grab me the latest date and group the serials but the state column doesnt change for some reason and stays at 0

```
Select MAX(date) as date, serial AS serial, state AS state
FROM testGraph
GROUP BY serial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the `where` clause:

```
select tg.*
from testgraph tg
where tg.date = (select max(tg2.date) from testgraph tg2 where tg2.serial = tg.serial);
```

Comment: I dont think the query worked, my table didn't populate

Comment: Actually never mind I got it to work.  the table was called testGraph not testgraph.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alan Does case matter in table names, or even column names in mysql? coz I don't think it does.

Comment: Well I tested it with phpmyadmin and it gave me an error saying table did not exist